# Binding an ASP.NET GridView Control to a string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I am trying to bind an ASP.NET `GridView` control to an `string` array and I get the following item:

> A field or property with the name
>   'Item' was not found on the selected
>   data source.

What is correct value I should use for DataField property of the asp:BoundField column in my GridView control.  Here is my source code:

ASPX page

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Click Me!" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
string[] MyArray = new string[1];
MyArray[0] = "My Value";
MyGridView.DataSource = MyArray;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

**UPDATE**

I need to have the `AutoGenerateColumns` attribute set to `false` because I need to generate additional `asp:CommandField` columns.  I have updated my code sample to reflect this scenario

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One method is to pass it a class with a single, named field.  That way, you can give it a name.

```
public class GridRecord
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then convert your string array to a list of the class

```
string[] MyArray = new string[1];
MyArray[0] = "My Value";
List<GridRecord> MyList = (
    from ar in myArray
    select new GridRecord
    {
        MyValue = ar
    }).ToList();
MyGridView.DataSource = MyList;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Now you can name your DataField property

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MyValue" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution using LINQ.

Comment: How can I use something like that above in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209825/how-to-combine-multiple-lists-and-use-as-a-gridview-datasource Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

After hours of search, I finally found that there is a special DataField for this case: "**!**"

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="!" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I hope it'll help someone one day :)

Comment: hmm, just tried it in a select box (drop-down) and it didn't work :( I wonder if that is specific to GridView. This seems such an obvious general requirement of data binding that I'm really surprised there isn't a proper answer

Comment: Wow. Do you have a link to where you found this info?

Comment: Still helpful in 2016-2017!

Answer (score 13):

Try replacing the BoundField with a TemplateField like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="String Value">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

BTW I lifted this from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502106/what-is-the-datakeyname-for-a-gridview-bound-to-a-string-array)

Comment: thanks. for some reason I can NEVER remember the Container.DataItem syntax :(

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example using the old DataGrid...so it appears that the "!" trick has widespread implementation. This worked under ASP.NET in VS2008. Of course, just substitute the right element names to use a GridView.

```
<%@ Page
    Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication2._Default"
%>
<%@Import
    Namespace="System.Collections.Generic"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/C#" runat="server">
        void initList()
        {           
        List<String> myList = new List<String>();
        myList.Add("Hello");
        myList.Add("Chatting");
        myList.Add("Goodbye");
        Grid1.DataSource = myList;
        Grid1.DataBind();
        }
    </script>    
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%initList(); %>
        <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="!" DataFormatString="Data: {0}"  HeaderText="Dyad"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So as a GridView the inner section would be

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="!" DataFormatString="Data: {0}"  HeaderText="Dyad"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

If you switch back and forth, notice that VS2008 (at least) cannot re-declare the control type in the Designer.cs class, so you'll have to change that by hand if just editing the element names.

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

The line of code

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Item" />
```

expects a column with the name of "Item," which you would have if you were binding to one of the DataSource controls such as SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource, or LinqDataSource.  Since you are binding to an IEnumerable, you have no such name.

Comment: Thank you, good point! I have now updated the code to use the correct name.