# LINQ - using result from one in another

Tags: c#, linq

I'm completely new to LINQ, i want to rewrite some of mine SQL querys into LINQ (just to learn) and i'v already stuck at the beginning. Probably solution is very simple but as i'v said I'm completely new and i didn't find solution to this.

I have one query :

```
string typMoneta = textBox1.Text;
var moneta = from x in db.grupyTowarowes
             where x.typ == typMoneta
             select new
             {
                 x.grupa
             };
```

Which works ok and when i set

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = moneta;
```

[Then i got output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDOwr.png)

And i want to use this output in my second query :

```
var query = from c in dbContext.Picking
            where c.Number == 1000 && c.Group == moneta
            select new
            {
                c.id
            };
```

Problem is with `c.Group == moneta`. I don't know the correct syntax. Could someone help me?

Comment: Whats the error you are receiving?

Comment: I don'f recive any error but the syntex which i show is incorrect, when i do it moneta.ToString() then instead of mine output i got query.

Comment: Queries are not normally things you would compare for equality. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Let me say again the fundamentally important thing that always confuses beginners: the value of a query expression is *an object that represents the query*. It is a *question*.  The value of a query expression is **not** the *answer* to that question.  You are saying "is this group the same query object as this one?" when I think you want to be saying something like "are the members of this group and the results of this query the same set of results?"

Comment: So basically what im trying to do is : I want to select grupa from one DataBase where typ=textBox.text and then select id where number==100 and c.grupa IN grupa from previous query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `moneta.Contains(c.Group)`. In first query, make sure you use `ToList()` to load data into memory.

```
IList<string> moneta = (from x in db.grupyTowarowes
    where x.typ == typMoneta
    select x.grupa).ToList();

var query = (from c in dbContext.Picking
    where c.Number == 1000 && moneta.Contains(c.Group) 
    select c.id).ToList();
```

Comment: I got error : "cannot convert from string to <anonymous type:string grupa>

Comment: In this part : moneta.Contains(c.Group)

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try without creating anonymous type - `new {}` in both query.

Comment: Now syntax is correct but i got no output i mean, i try to load query into dataGridView and nothing happend.

Comment: The data source becomes array of string, so use `DataField="!" ` or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/945756/296861) in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The `moneta` is an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` in your case is the type of `grupa`
That being said you should write your query like below:

```
var query = from c in dbContext.Picking
            where c.Number == 1000 
            && moneta.Contais(c.Group)
            select new
            {
                c.id
            };
```

or in fluent syntax like below:

```
var query = dbContext.Picking
                     .Where(pick => pick.Number == 1000 
                                 && moneta.Contains(pick.Group))
                     .Select(pick => pick.id);
```

Comment: I got error : "cannot convert from string to <anonymous type:string grupa>

Comment: The problem is about the types of `Group` and the types that are contained in `moneta`. Could you please specify them? Thanks

Comment: Group is string and moneta is IEnumerable as you said :)

Comment: @takiTamNick I suspect that `moneta`'s type is not `IEnumerable<string>`. So I think that if we figure out what is the type of `moneta` and how `moneta`'s items are associated with the `pick.Group`, then your problem would be solved.

Comment: IEnumerable<string> moneta = (from x in db.grupyTowarowes where x.typ == typMoneta select x.grupa).ToList();  So the type is IEnumerable<string>, but when i load it to DataGrigView i got 20 in every row and column is named "Length" instead of output which i had earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Note that moneta is not a collection of strings.  It's a collection of objects that have a string property named "grupa".

Does this work for you?

```
var query =
    from c in dbContext.Picking
    where c.Number == 1000
       && moneta.Any(m => m.grupa == c.Group)
    select new { c.id };
```

You could also do this:

```
// Get list of strings
var groups = moneta.Select(m => m.grupa).ToList();

// Get items where "Group" value is one of the strings in groups list, above.
var query =
    from c in dbContext.Picking
    where c.Number == 1000
       && groups.Contains(c.Group)
    select new { c.id };
```